# Health check of web page using curl

Tags: curl, monitoring

I'd like to do a health check of a service by calling a specific url on it. Feels like the simplest solution would be to use cron to do the check every minute or so. In case of errors, cron sends me an email.

I tried using cUrl for this but I can't get it to output messages only on errors. If I try to direct output to /dev/null, it prints out progress report.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5559  100  5559    0     0   100k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  106k
```

I tried looking through the curl options but I just can't find anything to suit the situation where you want it to be silent on success but make noise on errors.

Is there a way to make curl do what I want or is there some other tool I should be looking at?

Comment: How about using `icinga` or any other monitoring system?

Comment: I'm using this on a hobby project with limited resources on a shared host. I would love to use a monitoring system otherwise. Thanks for the tip anyways, I had not heard of icinga before

Comment: I would like to point out that share hosting providers will frown on this if you are hitting all the pages on your account too frequently. Providers typically have concurrent process limits and max exec time limits. Also this method will not be accurate if there is a network outage between you and the DC of the provider. You should investigate the domain access logs on your shared account. Typically there is plenty of traffic from bots and just random visitors that will give you a very good idea of how available your site is.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

What about `-sSf`? From the man pages:

> ```
>   -s/--silent
>      Silent or quiet mode. Do not show progress meter or error messages.  
>      Makes Curl mute.
>
>   -S/--show-error
>      When used with -s it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
>
>   -f/--fail
>      (HTTP)  Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly
>      done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts. In
>      normal  cases  when a HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it returns
>      an HTML document stating so (which often also describes  why  and  more).
>      This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22.
>
>      This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful
>      response codes will  slip  through,  especially  when  authentication  is
>      involved (response codes 401 and 407).
> ```

For example:

```
curl -sSf http://example.org > /dev/null
```

Comment: -sS didn't output the error message for some reason. I had to add -f also. The correct working command seems to be `curl -fsS http://example.org > /dev/null`. That will not output anything when nothing is wrong but it will print the status code on errors which is fine by me.

Comment: Ok, added `-f` for future references.

Comment: I added `echo` to so that I know the connection was successful. `curl -sSf http://example.org > /dev/null && echo "success"`

Comment: Thanks. Found this helpful. How about throwing in a -L to follow redirects?

Answer (score 38):

I think that for the simplest way to check if the site is alive, you could use the following method:

```
curl -Is http://www.google.com | head -n 1
```

This will return `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. If the return doesn't match your output then call out for help.

Comment: Checking status code makes probably more sense like the other proposals

Comment: I get "HTTP/1.1 302 Found".

Comment: This is great because it goes beyond a ping allowing me to check to see if my site is loading correctly (connection to mySQL etc.) and get more meaningful results.

Comment: What if the URL you want to test is a big file? like a pdf file or something? or a video stream which never ends?

Comment: @Freedo You can try the `-I` or `--head` flag which execute a `HEAD` request that fetches the response code and headers only. It may not work in all cases as severs can be configured to treat `GET` and `HEAD` requests differently.

Comment: strange why this answer had such less votes compared to the [highest voted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84818/11141) (exactly half the votes at this time).

Comment: Strange, it works differently inside shell function comparing alone.

Answer (score 12):

you can capture network timing stats from curl.  latencies of each phase in a request/response cycle can be useful to determine health.

```
$ URL=https://example.com
$ curl "$URL" -s -o /dev/null -w \
> "response_code: %{http_code}\n
> dns_time: %{time_namelookup}
> connect_time: %{time_connect}
> pretransfer_time: %{time_pretransfer}
> starttransfer_time: %{time_starttransfer}
> total_time: %{time_total}
> "
response_code: 200

dns_time: 0.029
connect_time: 0.046
pretransfer_time: 0.203
starttransfer_time: 0.212
total_time: 0.212
```

Answer (score 9):

You need the `-s` flag (silent), `-f` flag (fail with exit code on error) and can use the `-o` flag to redirect output:

```
curl www.websiteToTest.com -s -f -o /dev/null || echo "Website down." | mail -s "Website is down" admin@thesite.com
```

This is just an bad example for a simple cron script. Normally, you want to get only one mail if a website is down.

Answer (score 7):

Curl has very specific exit status codes
Why not just check for those?

```
#!/bin/bash

##name: site-status.sh

FAIL_CODE=6

check_status(){
    LRED="\033[1;31m" # Light Red
    LGREEN="\033[1;32m" # Light Green
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color


    curl -sf "${1}" > /dev/null

    if [ ! $? = ${FAIL_CODE} ];then
        echo -e "${LGREEN}${1} is online${NC}"
    else
        echo -e "${LRED}${1} is down${NC}"
    fi
}


check_status "${1}"
```

Usage:

```
$ site-status.sh example.com
```

Result:

```
$ example.com is online
```

Notes:

This script only checks if the site can be resolved.

This code should get you by if all you care about is the site being up or down.
However, if you make a few changes to the if/else block, you can easily test for other status codes if you wish

Comment: Plus one, I also check for `404 - not found` using the `header` flag in `curl`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euETo pipefail

timeout 3s curl -fIsS http://example.org > /dev/null
# and if you have TLS (https), check if it expires within next 20 days:
true | openssl s_client -connect example.org:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -checkend "$((20*24*60*60))"
```

Explanation:

- `timeout 3s` will set a 3-second timeout for your request. Answering slower is consedered to be "not healthy"
- curl `-f` flag will fail early, `-S` will show errors, `-s` will suppress normal output, `-I` will only fetch HTTP headers, not the content. (As always, more details are available on `man curl` command.)
- openssl `-checkend` directive checks expiry dates for a certificate. In my example, it is 20 days (specified in seconds).

Comment: I think you have the explanations of `-s` and `-S` swapped

Answer (score 2):

I was recently asked to come up with something that would act more like a sophisticated heartbeat.

```
for i in `curl -s -L cnn.com |egrep --only-matching "http(s?):\/\/[^ \"\(\)\<\>]*" | uniq` ; do curl -s -I $i 2>/dev/null |head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2; done
```

Or, expanded for a little more readability,

```
for i in $(curl -s -L cnn.com |egrep --only-matching 'http(s?):\/\/[^ \"\(\)\<\>]*' | uniq)
do
    curl -s -I "$i" 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2
done
```

What I did was `curl` a website, parse out all the links from the html, and then `curl` those parsed links, outputting only the status code.  Then I would search for http status codes >= 400 to find errors.

Answer (score 2):

This way will help you when trying to test the site when https is present:

```
#!/bin/bash
# put your domain in this var
https=https://www.somewebsite.com

# save the status in some variable 
status=`curl $https -k -s -f -o /dev/null && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "ERROR"`    

# print results (or use it in your scripts)
echo "testing $https=$status"
```