# using curl and shell script to restart apache

Tags: bash, shell-script, apache-httpd, curl

I would like to restart the **apache** server, when it's down. Hence I wrote a script below using **curl** and an **if** loop

```
curl example.com
si='curl example.com'
if test si !=0
then
service apache2 restart
fi
~
```

I expect to restart **apache** server, if the site is down

But It returns the following error

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 80: Connection refused
>
> autostart.sh: line 8: test: si: unary operator expected

Comment: did you check this post ? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84814/health-check-of-web-page-using-curl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl` seem to wait forever by default if the server doesn't respond, so if you must use `curl`, use it together with `--max-time` parameter.  1 line of script is enough to get this task done:

```
curl --max-time 15 example.com || sudo service apache2 restart
```

assuming vahaitech.com is your site, if curl doesn't finish downloading it in 15 seconds, then restart the apache2 service.

Comment: you used or condition , if curl returns error , the second will executed, otherwise curl only.May i correct

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for the previous command exit status flag, for example;

```
#!/bin/bash

curl example.com
if (( $? > 0 )); then
    sudo service apache2  restart
fi
```

This will look at the curls exit status, and if it's anything but 0 it will restart the apache2 server

If you want to suppress the output of these commands so it doesn't say anything, be sure to add

```
&>/dev/null
```

After each command